# The calculation of HashMap values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a project using the hash map. My aim is to calculate the survival rate of each unique characteristic.

Supposed I have an ArrayList to store the characteristics from enum.
Therefore, this ArrayList can contain multiple duplicate characteristics.

```
ArrayList<Object> allCharac = new ArrayList<Object>();
[MALE,FEMALE,FEMALE,MALE,FEMALE]


ArrayList<Object> characSurvive = new ArrayList<Object>();
[MALE,FEMALE]
```

Therefore, the survival ratio is:

```
male:0.50 = 1/2 (characSurvive/allCharac)
female:0.33 = 1/3
```

I can use the hash map to calculate the occurrence of each unique value in the ArrayList. However, how can I calculate the ratio by using the values from each hash map? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Map<Object,Integer> allCharacterCounts = new HashMap<Object,Integer>();
for (Object element: allCharac) {//from the above ArrayList
        if (allCharacterCounts.containsKey(element)) {
            allCharacterCounts.put(element, allCharacterCounts.get(element)+1);
        } else {
            allCharacterCounts.put(element, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `ArrayList<Oject,Integer> charac = new ArrayList<Object,Integer>();`? How can we have `ArrayList<Oject,Integer>`? Should it not be let's say String for MALE and FEMALE?

Comment: I have other `enum` type to be saved, it could be `ArrayList<Gender,Integer>`. @NitinBisht

Comment: Still, How is it possible? We have `ArrayList<E>` like this where E can be any `Object` type. However In your case `ArrayList<E, D>` what is `D` type. We don't have anything like this in Java

Comment: my bad, I'll edit that. Thank you for pointing out. @NitinBisht

Comment: It should be `ArrayList<String> charac = new ArrayList<String>();` like this. Secondly what is `allCharac` in `for (Object element: allCharac) {`. Edit your question and add about `allCharac` also.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've already modified that. @NitinBisht

Comment: Excellent. One last thing Explains a bit about the ratio part. How are you calculating its value?

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've added the calculation part. It is calculated by the number of keys:`characSurvive/allCharac`. @NitinBisht

Comment: Great!! Now you have total number of MALE and FEMALE in `allCharacterCounts`. You can simply iterate over its value based upon MALE and FEMALE and divide by `1`. You have only MALE and FEMALE in `characSurvive`. You do not need of `characSurvive` in your case. It can simply be done by dividing by `1` like `System.out.println(allCharacterCounts.get("MALE") / 1);`

Comment: Sir, why are we dividing by 1? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Because we have only 1 MALE and 1 FEMALE in `characSurvive`

Comment: okay, I got the logic! However, suppose there are more keys in the `characSurvive`, dividing by 1 won't work. @NitinBisht

Comment: Yes, you are right. I already mentioned earlier in your case you can divide by 1. If you have more element then you need to iterate over `characSurvive`. Secondly, I would recommend replacing ArrayList with HashSet for `characSurvive` because Set does not allow duplicate as you will always have unique element in `characSurvive`.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

enum Character {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> allCharac = List.of(Character.MALE, Character.FEMALE, Character.FEMALE, Character.MALE,
                Character.FEMALE);      
        List<Character> characSurvive = List.of(Character.MALE, Character.FEMALE);

        //Create frequency map
        Map<Character, Long> allCharacFreq = allCharac.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));

        for (Character character : characSurvive) {
            System.out.println(
                    character + ": " + String.format("%.2f", ((1.0 / allCharacFreq.get(character)) * 100)) + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MALE: 50.00%
FEMALE: 33.33%
```

If `characSurvive` also can have duplicate values, replace `1.0` with the frequency of each value from `characSurvive`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

enum Character {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> allCharac = List.of(Character.MALE, Character.FEMALE, Character.FEMALE, Character.MALE,
                Character.FEMALE);
        List<Character> characSurvive = List.of(Character.MALE, Character.MALE, Character.FEMALE);

        // Create frequency map for `allCharac`
        Map<Character, Long> allCharacFreq = allCharac.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));

        // Create frequency map for `characSurvive`
        Map<Character, Long> characSurviveFreq = characSurvive.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));

        for (Character character : characSurviveFreq.keySet()) {
            double percent = ((double) (characSurviveFreq.get(character)) / allCharacFreq.get(character)) * 100;
            System.out.println(character + ": " + String.format("%.2f", percent) + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
FEMALE: 33.33%
MALE: 100.00%
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I appreciate that. But what if the `characSurvive` also with multiple, duplicate keys? For example, if there are two `Character.MALE` that survived, the survival rate would be `100%`.

Comment: You are most welcome. `what if the characSurvive also with multiple, duplicate keys` - It's not difficult to do. Let me know if you want me to do it or you will try it first yourself.

Comment: I'll try it first. Thank you, sir, willing to solve and guide me =)

Comment: To be honest, my question is actually harder. My arrayList consists of multiple `enum` types. For example, I have also `Profession`, `BodyType`, etc. And I can't figure it out.

Comment: I've posted an update for this requirement (`what if the characSurvive also with multiple, duplicate keys`).

Comment: Thank you, sir. I understand your idea! It's clear and straight forward. May I ask a question off the topic? I've already practicing programming for a while, but I feel that I can't improve anymore. Is there any way for me to be better? @Arvind

Comment: You are most welcome. I suggest you start preparing for [OCP: Java SE 11 Developer Certification](https://education.oracle.com/oracle-certified-professional-java-se-11-developer/trackp_815). It will help you get rid of all such thoughts.

Comment: Thank you, sir, appreciate that =)